How to fetch a Author name and Book Binding Formate from an ISBN number?
We are setting up our online bookstore, and we aim to provide comprehensive information about each book on our product pages. To enhance the user experience, we are keen to display details such as the book binding format and author alongside other product information.
Upon reviewing our data structure, we noticed that we have an ISBN Metafield associated with every book in our inventory. We believe that with this information, it should be possible to fetch additional details like the book's binding format and author.

How can we leverage the ISBN number to fetch the book binding format and author automatically?

There are several APIs to lookup books by ISBN, some free, others paid and all with varying coverage and features. Your best bet is to Google and find one that suits your needs, but here's a comparison page for a small subset: https://www.vinzius.com/post/free-and-paid-api-isbn/.
